# What is FLA in the Elsevier manuscript submission checklist?

Tags: paper-submission, elsevier

Elsevier Clinical Biomechanics journal requires the submission of a [mandatory checklist](https://www.elsevier.com/__data/promis_misc/JCLB_authorchecklist_final.doc) along with the manuscript. One of its entries include the following.

> The section heading 'Introduction' should be used for all FLAs.

What is FLA in this context?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Elsevier nomenclature, **FLA** is an "article doc subtype" acronym for "Full length article". Other article type acronyms include **BRV** for book reviews, **NWS** for news, **PGL** for practice guideline, and so on.

The checklist requires you to have a section labelled "Introduction" for a full length article. For other article types, this is not required.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I just couldn't find anything relevant by searching FLA with Elsevier; you saved a lot a time for me. Thanks for the added info as well!

Comment: Nice; is this info written anywhere in Elsevier's website, or you just made sense of this?

Comment: @corey979 Thanks. It's actually relevant to Elsevier xml metadata provided to journal editorial and production staff. I was surprised that it leaked onto a checklist released to authors, given that it's used in the back end of the publishing workflow. I'm not certain it would be found on the Elsevier website, but I haven't checked. It's more likely to appear on an intranet.